# Areas\HelpPage\* (e.g. ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs) Could Not Be Found

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, nuget

A routine update recently broke compilation on a project of mine.
Numerous errors including: `Areas\HelpPage\ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs could not be found` appeared.
When doing a project-wide search, no references to these files were found.

According to source control, the following changes occurred in packages.config:

```
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
-   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
+   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Why did a routine library update cause errors related to seemingly irrelevant files,
 and how do I fix it? (Q&A format)

Answer (score 5):

I performed an internal file contents search for the name of one of the files, `ApiDescriptionExtensions`, which returned a reference to my .csproj file.

The solution to the compiler errors is to remove references to the offending files from .csproj (specific references shown below).

I suspect the installation of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage caused the problem due to the file names, but breaking the build because such files do not suddenly exist appears to be a bug that Microsoft or perhaps the NuGet package maintainer need to fix, even if such files existed at project creation and were later deleted.

Removal of the following .csproj lines allowed the project to build once again:

```
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ApiDescriptionExtensions.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\App_Start\HelpPageConfig.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\Controllers\HelpController.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\HelpPageConfigurationExtensions.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\DictionaryModelDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\EnumTypeModelDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\EnumValueDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\IModelDocumentationProvider.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\KeyValuePairModelDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ModelDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ModelDescriptionGenerator.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ModelNameAttribute.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ModelNameHelper.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ParameterAnnotation.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\ParameterDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\ModelDescriptions\SimpleTypeModelDescription.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\Models\HelpPageApiModel.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\HelpPageSampleGenerator.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\HelpPageSampleKey.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\ImageSample.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\InvalidSample.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\ObjectGenerator.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\SampleDirection.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\SampleGeneration\TextSample.cs" />
<Compile Include="Areas\HelpPage\XmlDocumentationProvider.cs" />
```

As you can see, just remove every  line containing reference to `Areas\HelpPage`

Comment: This is not a solution, you simple exclude the files from the project.